# Find measure of angles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral and $M$ be the midpoint of the segment $BC$ such that $$∠AMD = 90^\circ,\ ∠ADM = 15^\circ,$$
>   and $$AD = AB + CD.$$ Find $∠BAD$.

I try to find an additional construction but I don't know. Can you help me with one idea?

Answer (score 0):

Let us define an point $X$ on $AD$.
Construct a circle,$Σ$ of radius $AX$, taking point $A$ as a center.

Construct another circle,$Ω$ of radius $(AD-AX)$, taking $D$ as a center.

Point $M$ must lie on the tangent to $Σ$ and $Ω$ (whose points of contact on $Σ$  and $Ω$ define the points $B$ and $C$ respectively).

Also, $M$ becomes the midpoint of $BC$ as tangents drawn from an external point to a circle are equal.
$(MB=MX=MC)$.

Join $MX$ (which becomes a perpendicular to $AD$)

This gives us an imaginary contruction.

Tangents draw to a circle are perpendicular to the radius at the point of contact.
So, angles $MBA$ and $MCD$ are right angles.

Also, tangents drawn to a circle from a given point are equally inclined to the line joining the center to the point.
So, angles $BMA$ and $XMA$ are equal and are both $15°$
$(90°-MAD=90°-75°)$.

Thus, in $ΔBAM$,
angle $BAM=75°$.

And finally,
Angle $BAD=150°$.                                                            Ans.

Comment: By contruction also, it was found to be right.